# How to build net core 3.0 app using VS 2019

Tags: .net-core

I want to compile a .net project using net core 3, in the hope that it will then run on the latest Ubuntu.

I have downloaded VS2019, and the net core 3 SDK, and enabled previews in Tools/Options/Environment/Preview features.

I created a new project (it defaulted to net core 3.0), added some source files, and tried to build it.

I got these errors:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: BaseCampApi, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview5-011568\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(157,5): message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
    1>c:\dev\BaseCampApi\BaseCampApi\BasecampApi.cs(18,17,18,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    1>c:\dev\BaseCampApi\BaseCampApi\BasecampApi.cs(303,17,303,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FileExtensionContentTypeProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    1>Done building project "BaseCampApi.csproj" -- FAILED.
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What do I do to get it to compile?

Comment: what kind of project did you create? it seems like you are trying to compile aspnet sources as a dotnet project, missing the reference to the aspnet sdk.

Comment: This is a console app, no ASP involved.

Comment: Then `AspNetCore` isn't referenced (because this isn't ASP.net)

Comment: @NikkiLocke Well, what did you expect to happen then? You have reference to AspNetCore in a console application. Create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application and put the code there.

Comment: "API" sounds a lot like aspnet though. also the error about a missing "AspNetCore" namespace indicates you do actually try to compile an aspnet core api, not a console application.

Comment: My bad - I reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles to do MIME type translation. If you want to rephrase your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @NikkiLocke I've added an edit to my answer to reflect over the comments. It is a good idea to either accept it or answer your own question with the solution of the problem as for other members's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you restore all dependencies?

Try running `dotnet restore` and then `dotnet build` if you're using the terminal or just Nuget Restore through VS.

If it doesn't help, you'll have to remove some artifacts from the `.csproj` file and restore dependencies after that. Look for something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.core\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Remove it and reference it anew by restoring with Nuget.

Also, make sure you're actually in an ASP.NET project and not a console one, for example. Your project is called "***Api**" which in the general case should mean that it is an ASP.NET project indeed but you never know.

---

**EDIT after comments:**

So, it turned out you have a Console application after all and you're referencing packets from ASP.NET. Either create a new ASP.NET Web App and move your code there or include the framework packets(if you need them that much AND if they're actually compatible considering the task in hand). Most probably there should be an alternative ones for console applications, though, so you **should** use them instead).

Comment: The reference was to Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles in order to use FileExtensionContentTypeProvider to obtain a mime type from a file extension. Alternative suggestions welcome.

Comment: @NikkiLocke The solution for .NET was `System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`. However, for .NETCore, I suppose you can use this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeMapping/, as it is based on .NET Standard.